# IFrame doesn't load content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I try to code a info-screen for our school hall. Our Timetable is available on a internet page, but it don't look very nice and you can only show the room occupancy of one room at the same time. So I tried to write a header and sidebar in html/css and switch through the online room occupancy tables via javascript and iFrame, which i can show on firefox fullscreen mode. So all I want to do is to load a new external page into my iFrame every 10 seconds. So I tried this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var counter = 1;

setInterval(function() {

    var jetzt = new Date(Date.now());
    var date = jetzt.toISOString().split("T")[0];

    switch (counter) {
        case 0:
            $( "#welcome" ).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
            $( "#welcome" ).css("color", "#000000");
            $( "#013" ).css("background-color", "#F39100");
            $( "#013" ).css("color", "#ffffff");
            $( "contentFrame" ).attr('src', 'welcome.html');
            break;
        case 1:
            $( "#004" ).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
            $( "#004" ).css("color", "#000000");
            $( "#welcome" ).css("background-color", "#F39100");
            $( "#welcome" ).css("color", "#ffffff");
            $( "contentFrame" ).attr('src', "https://splan.fh-rosenheim.de/splan/mobile?lan=de&sel=ro&pu=12&ro=318&sd=true&dfc=" + date + "&loc=4&sa=false&cb=o&act=print&html=true");
            break;
        case 2:
            $( "#005" ).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
            $( "#005" ).css("color", "#000000");
            $( "#004" ).css("background-color", "#F39100");
            $( "#004" ).css("color", "#ffffff");
            $( "contentFrame" ).attr('src', "https://splan.fh-rosenheim.de/splan/mobile?lan=de&sel=ro&pu=12&ro=319&sd=true&dfc=" + date + "&loc=4&sa=false&cb=o&act=print&html=true");
            break;

            ...

        counter = (counter + 1)%8;

}, 3000);
});
```

The script works for the css changes, they change every three seconds (smaller time for testing), but my iFrame content stays at the first loaded content, no matter which it is. I tried to load a room occupancy table first - it works. Then I tried my Welcome page - it works too. But if i change the src-attribute of the iframe nothing happens. On some pages I've read i should try the following codes, if it doesn't work:

```
<object>.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

But it only crashes my whole script if I call

```
$( "contentFrame" ).contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I force the iFrame to load the new source?

Thanks and best regards

Chriss

Comment: `<object>.contentWindow` - the object here would be a reference to a DOM element. `$( "contentFrame" )` however returns a jQuery object. You can use `$( "contentFrame" )[0]` to get the reference to the first DOM element in that selection.

Comment: I think you meant `$( "#contentFrame" )` and not  `$( "contentFrame" )`

Comment: @BrahmaDev I thank you very much. I sat hours on this problem and am still to blind to find a simple error like this. Shame on me :). What a rookie failure.